# (Solved) Will 2.82 files work in 2.79?

Tags: versions, compatibility

I have a question, if I model an object and I do the materials, the textures, the animations all that is possible is unimaginable on the version 2.82 of Blender, and that I want to copy / paste on the version 2.79 of Blender because I need an addon to export which is not available on version 2.8, will i have issues/error or something? sorry for my english.

Comment: What add-on do you need?

Comment: it is an addon that allows me to export in .igs and .ia format for train simulator.

Comment: Please accept or post an answer if solved.

Answer (score 1):

Project files (.blend) created with newer versions of  Blender generally can't be opened by older versions. Blender isn't designed to be forward compatible.

Comment: For .blend files, I know it's impossible to open them, but I'm talking about copying / pasting an object, I managed to do it, and the person who created the addon told me that I could totally do my work on 2.8 and then copied the object on 2.79 to use the addon, that's what I did and it works, the problem is solved

Comment: Great that it works in your use case. Copy and paste may work, but it's not guaranteed to function. For instance you will run into issues when your material contains the mapping node. There are many other aspects that could cause problems.